# Multiple select list - disabling items already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown

I have 2 or more select lists with the same options.  Once an Item is selected in one of the select lists, I don't want the user to be able to select it in another select list.

However, I cannot figure out how to set the value to disabled.  Opt.prop("disabled","disabled") is not working.

```
<select id="select1" class="equipment-listbox">
    <option value="">-- Select Tool --></option>
    <option value="Drill">Drill<option>
    <option value="Scalpel">Scalpel<option>
    <option value="Syringe">Syringe<option>
    <option value="Calipers">Calipers<option>
    <option value="Chisel">Chisel<option>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="equipment-listbox">
    <option value="">-- Select Tool --></option>
    <option value="Drill">Drill<option>
    <option value="Scalpel">Scalpel<option>
    <option value="Syringe">Syringe<option>
    <option value="Calipers">Calipers<option>
    <option value="Chisel">Chisel<option>
</select>

$(".equipment-listbox").click(function () {
    var thisSelect = document.getElementById(this.id);

    $(".equipment-listbox").each(function (e, val) {
        var otherSelect = document.getElementById(val.id);
        if (thisSelect.id != otherSelect.id) {

            for (var opt in thisSelect.options) {

                if (otherSelect.selectedIndex == opt) { --if otherSelect has a value in thisSelect...set to disabled
                    //console.log("setting option to disabled");
                    opt.prop("disabled", "disabled");
                }

            }

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each select you need to disable all options selected but its own selected option. Check this example.

```js
let selects = $(".equipment-listbox");

selects.change(function() {
    // getting all selected values
    let selected = selects.map((i, s) => s.value).get();
    selects.find("option").each(function(i, o) {
        // disable option if it is selected in other selects
        // (you can set the 'disabled' propery to true or false)
        $(o).prop("disabled", o.value.length &&                 //enable empty values
                              selected.includes(o.value) &&
                              $(o).parent().val() !== o.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" class="equipment-listbox">
    <option value="">-- Select Tool --></option>
    <option value="Drill">Drill<option>
    <option value="Scalpel">Scalpel<option>
    <option value="Syringe">Syringe<option>
    <option value="Calipers">Calipers<option>
    <option value="Chisel">Chisel<option>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="equipment-listbox">
    <option value="">-- Select Tool --></option>
    <option value="Drill">Drill<option>
    <option value="Scalpel">Scalpel<option>
    <option value="Syringe">Syringe<option>
    <option value="Calipers">Calipers<option>
    <option value="Chisel">Chisel<option>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="equipment-listbox">
    <option value="">-- Select Tool --></option>
    <option value="Drill">Drill<option>
    <option value="Scalpel">Scalpel<option>
    <option value="Syringe">Syringe<option>
    <option value="Calipers">Calipers<option>
    <option value="Chisel">Chisel<option>
</select>
```

A little explanation:

When each select changes its value, we do the following:

1) `selects.map((i, s) => s.value).get()` - get values of all selects and collect them to an array.
2) `selects.find("option").each(function(i, o)` - for each option in every select we set `disabled` to `true` if:

- this option value is not empty (`o.value.length` will be converted to `false` if it is equal to `0` and to `true` otherwise)
- and it is already selected (`selected.includes(o.value)`)
- but it is selected not in the current select: `$(o).parent().val() !== o.value`

Comment: Is there a good online tutorial/youtube video/etc to explain this in greater detail?

Comment: You're welcome! Regarding tutorials, take a look at this [JS tutorial](https://javascript.info/array-methods#searching-in-array). And for jQuery, I think, their documrntation is the best tutorial: [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/), [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional

```
if (otherSelect.selectedIndex == opt) {
```

will never be satisfied, because your for loop is returning Option objects.  You're essentially asking if the option object is an integer (an integer is returned by selectedIndex).

I'd change it to something like this:

```
if (otherSelect.value == opt.value) { 
  $(opt).prop("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".equipment-listbox").change(function () {
    var item=$(this).val(), id=$(this).attr("id");
    $(".equipment-listbox:not(#" + id + ")").children().each(function() {
        if ($(this).val()===item) {
            $(this).prop("disabled", "true");
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1" class="equipment-listbox">
<option value="">-- Select Tool --></option>
<option value="Drill">Drill<option>
<option value="Scalpel">Scalpel<option>
<option value="Syringe">Syringe<option>
<option value="Calipers">Calipers<option>
<option value="Chisel">Chisel<option>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="equipment-listbox">
<option value="">-- Select Tool --></option>
<option value="Drill">Drill<option>
<option value="Scalpel">Scalpel<option>
<option value="Syringe">Syringe<option>
<option value="Calipers">Calipers<option>
<option value="Chisel">Chisel<option>
</select>
```